# Phonegap application not install into iphone 6

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I am facing with one issue that i am going to install the phone-gap application into iPhone 6 an it shows the error message  "Frame Load Interrupted".

Can you help me sort out this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the log output ? @Paresh

Comment: Now it is working fine.

Comment: Issue is that we have not add iphone6 UDID into apple developer account